# How to enforce single plot instance(when open new plot,close previous one automatically)?

Tags: matplotlib, pydev, seaborn

I am using pydev as python IDE.Each running will open a new plot,just wondering is there any easy way to enforce single plot instance (when open new plot,close previous one automatically)?